# Fancy package and Contents header

Tags: fancyhdr

I used the following package and commands to change the headers of my thesis, so to remove the default uppercaseness and make them look nice:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ #1}{}} 
\cfoot{} 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

In the example, the header of chapter 1 looks nice; however, these commands do not affect the Contents headers (and neither those of the List of Figures and List of Tables sections), that remain written in capital letters. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us (i) what document class you are using and (ii) how you produce your bibliography and table of contents? Ideally you would show us a minimal example document that we can just copy, paste and compile, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this, I'll edit the post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the ToC/LoF/LoT all *explicitly* issue a `\MakeUppercase` as part of setting the headers. For example, here's the definition of `\tableofcontents` from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

`\listofofigures` and `\listoftables` have similar `\MakeUppercase`s. You can restrict the workings of `\MakeUppercase` on these `\...name` macros by making them robust ([`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides `\robustify`). That is, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify\contentsname
\robustify\listfigurename
\robustify\listtablename
```

---

If you're loading `\usepackage[<language>]{babel}`, the following might be a viable alternative to the above solution:

```
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{%
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax
  \oldtableofcontents
}}
\let\oldlistoffigures\listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{{%
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax
  \oldlistoffigures
}}
\let\oldlistoftables\listoftables
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{{%
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax
  \oldlistoftables
}}
```

The intent is to set `\MakeUppercase` to do nothing (`\relax`) within a grouped call to set the ToC/LoF/LoT.

Comment: I noticed your suggestion perfectly works, unless, in the long list of packages I'm using in my thesis, I add the following: \usepackage[english]{babel}.  For some weird reason I really don't get, it is like adding this line nullifies the previous command you suggested, restoring the uppercaseness. Do you know why?

Comment: @Mary: Try with the added solution at the end of my answer. It works on my end.